# Using a bitset to get a conditional sum of array items without using loop

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sum, bitset

There are a bitset `b` and an array `arr`. I would like to get the sum of the array by using the bitset, so that `arr[i]` is summed only if `b[i]` is set.

Example:

```
bitset<4> b("1001"); 
arr[4] = {5,4,3,1};

===> the sum would be 1+5 = 6.
```

Obviously, I could use a loop. But this kind of computation is repeated multiple times. Is there a more effective way without a loop ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You will need a loop to add more than one bit.  How complex the loop is depend on your implementation.  There is no binary operation for what you want. *Correction:  you may not need a loop, but the operation needs to be repeated.*

Comment: Hi, Thomas, Thank you for your answer. However, I am still confused. What do you mean by "operation needs to be repeated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would probably to iterate through a loop and add depending if the current bit is set.

Perhaps the use of bit shifting instead of accessing directly to bit n could avoid some hidden gymnastics by the standard library to extract a specific bit, but this is yet to be proven by benchmarking.:

```
int sum=0;
for (size_t i=b.size(); i; i--, b>>=1) 
    if (b[0])
        sum+=arr[i-1];
```

For the completeness and the fun,  if you could live with a `vector<bool>` instead of a `bitset<>`, you could just use the standard library:

```
vector<bool> b{1,0,0,1}; 
int arr[4] = {5,4,3,1};
int test=inner_product(begin(arr), end(arr), b.begin(), 0);
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/ccYslS)

---

#### Edit: additional infos - trust your optimizing compiler

I experimented on godbolt online compiler with gcc 7.2 for x86-64 platform to look at the assembly produced by the different variants above.

The simplest solution, iterating trough the loop and conditionally adding the items is extremely fast:

- With constant values as in your example, the compiler is able via constant propagation and determine the result of `6` immediately (see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/tyTHnS)).
- If you have small size data structures, the compiler will automatically unroll the loop, making it lightening fast ([14 sequential assembler instruction for 4 elements](https://godbolt.org/g/p2r9qA)), without any loop index to maintain.
- However the optimizer may choose not to unroll the loop for larger sizes.  In my experiment, up to up to a size of 17 items the loop is unrolled, with 18 elements it's a [real loop](https://godbolt.org/g/jJhYws))

The bit shifting alternative is very close:

- Up to 17 items, the loop is unrolled and the code generated is exacly the same as with the simple loop.
- From 18 elements onwards, a loop is generated, which has [one assembly instruction less](https://godbolt.org/g/ve5pEi) per iteration. It seems a little fastern but only a benchmark could really make the difference which might be in the nanosecond range.

Of course, the `inner_product` is much heavier, because it really makes a multiplication which require to convert the bools to ints, and it has to cope with a dynamic size for the bool vector.

Comment: Possible worth mentioning that we needn’t necessarily mutate `b`; in this example the bitset and the array have the same size, so we could check the corresponding bit using the `i` iterate (along with some simple index mapping logic).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more effective way without a loop ?

The common for-loop always has three inefficiencies that can easily be side-stepped: the stride increment, the end-of-loop test, and end-of-loop jump.  However, these are each VERY small, so don't get your hopes up.

You can easily "unroll" the loop for that very small gain, at the cost of more lines of code (trade space for performance).  This scheme gets tedious as the size of bitset and the array grow ...

```
std::bitset<4> b     (std::string("1001"));
std::array<int, 4> a {{5,4,3,1}};

// loop form
int sum = 0;               
for (uint i=0; i < 4; ++i) // stride increment, test end-of-loop
{
   if (b[i]) sum += a[i];
}                          // end-of-loop jump
std::cout << "\n  sum: " << sum << std::endl;


// unrolled loop form -- no stride increment, 
//                       no end-of-loop test, and
//                       no end-of-loop jump
sum = 0;
if (b[0]) sum += a[0];    
if (b[1]) sum += a[1];
if (b[2]) sum += a[2];
if (b[3]) sum += a[3];
// bigger array, more lines ...

std::cout << "\n  sum: " << sum << std::endl;
```

Note - A similar approach supports big loops.  In this example, each 'line' performs 1 sum.  For big loops, each line can invoke a function that performs 10 (or 100 or 1000, etc.) of these lines.  I can not remember the last time I saw another programmers unrolled-loop code.  The gain is very small.

Comment: Many modern compilers allow use of pushing and popping pragma directives to e.g. specifically specify a given (simple) loop to be unrolled, in case on would like to resort to such an optimization.